# Add additional data to RecyclerView items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a functioning RecyclerView which works fine with the given data I provide via ListAdapter as shown below. What I now want is to add additional data to my list items.

```
class IngredientAdapter(
    private val ingredientClickListener: IngredientClickListener
) : ListAdapter<Ingredient, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(EventDiffCallback()) {

    private val adapterScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    fun submitIngredientsList(list: List<Ingredient>?) {
        adapterScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                submitList(list)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to do that properly or if RecyclerViews are even capable of doing this. The only way I am able to see is merging both data classes (*Ingredient* plus the new one) together and submit them as list together to the adapter but this seems messy and I am looking for a better way.

So my question is: How to feed data into my list items without merging it together with the data I already have? Is RecyclerView the wrong choice in my case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say you want to add additional data, what sort of data do you mean? Could it be something you could add with View.tag?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! The data I want to add is of similiar kind like the one which already part of the Adapter. It is data stored in a room database which I usually access via view models. I dont know much about setTag (can I retrieve the Tag from withing the layout file?) but what just has come into my mind is adding the data in onBindViewHolder() by just calling holder.binding.mTextField = myData on my Viewholder. I just dont know if this is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution: I submitted the additional data list just how like the other one but did not attach it directly to the ListAdapter since this is not possible.

In the function `onBindViewHolder` after getting the item for the current position I use this information to retrieve the correct element from the new data list. Then I attach the data to the view by calling using the viewholders view binding

```kotlin
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolder -> {
                val resources = holder.itemView.context.resources
                val ingredientItem = getItem(position)
                holder.bind(ingredientClickListener, ingredientItem)
                val groceryInStock: GroceryInStock? = availableGroceries.firstOrNull{ 

                    ingredientItem.grocery.groceryId == it.grocery.groceryId 
                }

                holder.binding.listItemAvailableAmount.text = groceryInStock.amount
            }
        }
    }
```

Since the data I add fully depends on the already existing item being displayed I did not make any changes to the functions `areItemsTheSame` and `areContentsTheSame` in my overriden `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` class.